# Google maps API v3 - Polyline with symboles duplicated at wrong place - google chrome

Tags: google-maps, google-chrome, google-maps-api-3

While creating a polyline with a sequence of symboles,
Seems like some html "canvas" are duplicated,
and displayed at wrong places on the map.

The bug occurs on "google chrome".

Attached a screenshot.
Also attached a link to js-fiddle.

[image: screenshot- duplicated canvas tiles.]

[link to js-fiddle - please view on google chrome](http://jsfiddle.net/tjqo684f/)

```
function initialize() {
var gm = google.maps,
    mapOptions = {
        zoom: 17,
        center: new gm.LatLng(55.685336941597804, 21.11585641885563),
        mapTypeId: gm.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    },
    map = new gm.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions),
    points = [
        //new gm.LatLng(55.685025, 21.11899500000004),
        new gm.LatLng(55.683228369431774, 21.11899500000004),
        new gm.LatLng(55.68333671468528, 21.117905037957826),
        new gm.LatLng(55.68364868408562, 21.116946525082994),
        new gm.LatLng(55.68412665376389, 21.116235063478825),
        new gm.LatLng(55.6847129783503, 21.11585646893286),
        new gm.LatLng(55.685336941597804, 21.11585641885563),
        new gm.LatLng(55.6859232843305, 21.116234936678893),
        new gm.LatLng(55.685025, 21.11899500000004)
    ],
    iconSequence = {
        icon: {
            path: gm.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW
        },
        repeat: '12px',
    },
    line = new gm.Polyline({
        map: map,
        path: points,
        icons: [iconSequence]
    });
```

}

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 0):

The bug has resolved at Chrome version: 60.

(It is reproduceable at Chrome 59).

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The issue was reported in Google issue tracker some time ago: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/38211242